# Artifactory PyPi repo layout with build promotion

Tags: python, artifactory

**Q1:**
I have an Artifactory PyPi enabled repo *my-pypi-repo* where I can publish my packages. When uploading via python `setup.py -sdist`, I get a structure like this:

```
my-pypi-repo|
            |my_package|
                       |x.y.z|
                             |my_package-x.y.z.tar.gz
```

The problem is this structure will not match any "allowed" repo layout in Artifactory, since *[org]* or *[orgPath]* are mandatory:

> Pattern '[module]/[baseRev]/[module]-[baseRev].[ext]' must at-least
>   contain the tokens 'module', 'baseRev' and 'org' or 'orgPath'.

I managed to publish to a path by 'hacking' the package name to `myorg/my_package`, but then pip cannot find it, so it's pretty useles.

**Q2:**
Has anyone tried the "ci-repo" and "releases-repo" with promotion for Python using Artifactory?

What I would like to achieve:

**CI repo:**
`my_package-1.2.3+build90.tar.gz` When this artifact gets promoted build metadata gets dropped

**Releases repo:**
`my_package-1.2.3.tar.gz`

I can achieve this via repo layouts (providing I resolve Q1). The problem is how to deal with the "embedded" version inside my Python script, hardcoded in setup.py.

I'd rather not rebuild the package again, for best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am running into the same issue in regards to your first question/problem.  When configuring my system to publish to artifactory using pip, it uses the format you described.

As you mentioned, the `[org]` or `[orgPath]` is mandatory and this basically breaks all the REST API functionality, like searching for latest version, etc.  I'm currently using this as my Artifact Path Pattern:

```
[org]/[module]/[baseRev].([fileItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev].([fileItegRev]).[ext]
```

The problem is that pip doesn't understand the concept of `[org]` in this case.  I'm temporarily using a python script to publish my packages to Artifactory to get around this.  Hopefully this is something that can be addressed by the jFrog team.

The python script simply uses Artifactory's REST API to publish to my local pypi repository, tacking on a few properties so that some of the REST API functions work properly, like [Artifact Latest Version Search Based on Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactLatestVersionSearchBasedonProperties).

I need to be able to use that call because we're using Chef in-house and we use that method to get the latest version.  The `pypi.version` property that gets added when publishing via `python setup.py sdist upload -r local` doesn't work with the REST API so I have to manually add the `version` property.  Painful to be honest since we can't add properties when using the upload option with setup.py.  Ideally I'd like to be able to do everything using pip, but at the moment this isn't possible.

I'm using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package and the upload method in the Artifactory documentation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution). Here is the function I'm using to publish adding a few properties (feel free to add more if you need):

```
def _publish_artifact(name, version, path, summary):
    base_url = 'http://server:8081/artifactory/{0}'.format(PYPI_REPOSITORY)
    properties = ';version={0};pypi.name={1};pypi.version={0};pypi.summary={2}'\
             .format(version, name, summary)
    url_path = '/Company/{0}/{1}/{0}-{1}.zip'.format(name, version)
    url = '{0}{1}{2}'.format(base_url, properties, url_path)

    dist_file = r'{0}\dist\{1}-{2}.zip'.format(path, name, version)
    files = {'upload_file': open(dist_file, 'rb')}
    s = requests.Session()
    s.auth = ('username', 'password')
    reply = s.put(url, files=files)
    logger.info('HTTP reply: {0}'.format(reply))
```

Comment: Can you use `pip` to *install* the packages uploaded to Artifactory in subfolders? I could cope with publishing them not using `pip`, but need my users to be able to install the packages via pip.

Comment: Yes, you can search and install for the packages manually uploaded and placed in a different folder structure:

`pip3 search my-package --index http://server:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-test-local`

and install:

`pip3 install my-package -i http://server:8081/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-test-local/simple`

Comment: Are you using promotion for your Artifactory pypi repos?

Comment: Not at the moment, we're currently moving artifacts manually.  We could since we're tagging each artifact with custom properties.

Answer (score 1):

A1: Artifactory layouts aren't enforcive, you can deploy any file under any path to any repo. Some layout-related features, like snapshots cleanup won't work then, but I don't think you need them anyway.

A2: The best solution will be to code your promotion in [a promotion user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Promotions). Renaming artifacts on the fly during their promotion to another repo is one of the most popular scenarios of this kind of plugin.

Comment: A1: Those layout related features is exactly what I'm after, CI artifacts cleanup being one of them. I wish layouts were enforced, btw.  A2: Seems to me a bit overkill to create a plugin for renaming artifacts on promotion, especially when you can achieve the same with layouts. In any case, my concern there is with the version hardcoded in my package `setup.py` more than the package name itself.

Comment: A1: In that case you have to have the directories corresponding to the organization. Enforcement can be implemented (by user plugin, yup). A2: Changing the content of the file is also easy with the plugin, e.g. see [renaming the version from SNAPSHOT to release](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/build/promotion.groovy).

Comment: A1: I'm trying to figure out how to add the directories to the Python publish scripts. Any pointers on this? A2: That looks pretty complicated to me :). Given we're talking about Python source code, I think I'd better change the version in the source code and publish again. The only downside I can see is I'm loosing the traceability with those artifacts